# jQuery Datatable unable to feed json into the table

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, datatable

This is the format of the json that I have received as a reponse from the django backend. How can I make datatable read this into the table?

```
[{
    "model": "model name", 
       "pk": 2, 
   "fields": {
         "name1": .., 
         "name2": ..,
         }
  },
  {
    "model": "model name", 
       "pk": 2, 
   "fields": {
         "name1": .., 
         "name2": ..,
         }
  }
]
```

Javascript:

```
    $(document).ready( function () {
            $('#tablename')
            .on('xhr.dt', function(e, settings, json){
                console.log(json)
            })
            .DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "list",
                    "dataSrc": "",
                },
            });
    });
```

The console.log(json) prints the json as a string instead of a JS object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hocus pocus in that :

```
$('#tablename').DataTable({
   ...
   columns : [
      { data : 'fields.name1' },
      { data : 'fields.name2' }
      //etc
   ]        
});
```

---

**Update**  (after investigating OP website)

1. Your http://anime.moxware.com/list/ works perfectly fine
2. http://anime.moxware.com/list/?_12234343434 does too
3. What did you expect

   ```
   $.ajax({
       dataType: 'json',
       type: 'GET',
       url: 'list',
   }).done(addDataToTable.bind(this));

   function addDataToTable(data){
      this.dt.rows.add(data).draw();
   }
   ```

   to do?

Do it the *straight* well documented way, as hundreds of examples demonstrates to do it :

```html
<table id="animelist" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

```js
var dt = $('#animelist').DataTable({
   ajax : {
        url : 'list',
        dataSrc : ''
   },
   processing: true,
   columns : [
       {"data" : 'fields.anime_name', "title": "Anime Title"},
       {"data" : 'fields.season_no', "title": "Season"},
       {"data" : 'fields.episodes_watched', "title": "Episodes Watched"},
       {"data" : 'fields.total_episodes', "title": "Total Episodes"}
    ]
});
```

And nothing more. No creative written ajax calls, no alternative adding methods, no double up of field, name or title definitions, no trailing commas or anything else.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
This is the error shown in the console from jQuery datatable.

Comment: Anyway I have used another method to work around this. for some reason, the ajax call by the datatable have a weird url with GET parameter.

Comment: @Mox "_Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined_" you probably have a different number of columns in `<th>` than numbers of fields specified from the JSON - they should match, see example with your JSON -> **http://jsfiddle.net/vqo8o71d/**

Comment: The ajax called by datatable does get a response. And I have pasted it in the javascript to load directly. It works. However, when i change the source to ajax, it will never work. =/

Comment: I have updated the code on the jsfiddle. If you don't mind, take a look and let me know what is going on. http://jsfiddle.net/vqo8o71d/3/
Here I would like to point out the difference in the ajax call recorded by the browser. If I have used $.ajax(), the url is correct which is "list". 
 however, when I have used the "ajax" in datatables, it will give me "list?_342341323" which I believe is the cause of the issue.

Comment: `_342341323` is normal behaviour. It is [jQuerys non-caching variable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12714563/1407478) set `cache : true` in the ajax call if it somehow disturb your code (is a little bit surprised, cache is true by default). jsFiddle does not support ajax, but here is proof you are on the right track (after placing the anime-contant in a varaible) -> http://jsfiddle.net/vqo8o71d/4/

Comment: so does that mean the issue is actually a bug in the jQuery/datatable?

I have verified using the sample that you have shown in jsfiddle. anyway here is the actual site, so u may examine the actual code in the web page. http://anime.moxware.com/

Comment: @mox, it works for me - your page looks just fine, 9 rows is shown.

Comment: thats is because i m using external ajax call to load the table instead of the ajax provided by datatable

Comment: @Mox, see update. You can easily assume - when so simple code not is working for you - that it is yourself who have made a mistake, it is by certain not a bug - and the solution is not to try to make it even more complicated but more simple - and the most simple is to do it as all the documentation and manuals tells you to do it. I can assure you the code in the updated answer works. Took the sourcecode from your site and changed it back to what you probably have started out with.

Comment: thank you so much for the help. The problem has been resolved based on your solution. So the trailing comma in the last element of the array/dictionary actually caused issue i suppose?